# broadcom 4233 drivers unable to install

Tags: wireless, internet, mac, macbook-pro

so i just updated my 2009 macbook pro to ubuntu 20.04 and now the drivers for the network card isnt working anymore, i've tried installing them via "additional drivers" and running

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

getting the error code

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

results after running

```
sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version

Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5
Config-Version: 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5
```

and also ran

```
uname -r
```

and got

```
5.8.0-36-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Version` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.